# Clicking of Brakes

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, windshield-wipers

My vehicle was recently in a accident involving a raccon (go figure) and did a lot of damage. I already had it checked out and they said it needed alot body work and possible wheel alignment. However this morning I kept hearing a clicking sound when I turned my windshield wipers on and it would immediately stop when I turned them off. I even tried pressing on the brakes when going at fast speeds and at low speeds but no clicking. I was wondering what this could be and if it may be serious.

Comment: What is the connection of the brakes and the wipers clicking?

Comment: also the sound seems to coming from the left driver side brake.

Comment: not too sure but its only when i turn the wipers on

Answer (score 2):

If there was any damage to the hood or the left side front quarter panel it could have bent a cowl or some other shroud near your wiper motor or wiper connector arms (hidden under the cowl at the bottom of your windshield). If it's a small interference it could be "clicking" past it rather than totally being stuck.

Try running the wipers without the engine on and get outside to locate the sound more precisely.